# Embedding a video playlist from fields

Tags: nodes

I want to allow users to copy YouTube URLs to a field in a node form, then have the node display a slideshow of those fields. Is this possible? I looked at the media front and ddblock  modules, but those draw from multiple nodes and not multiple fields in a single node.

Comment: you can use media module http://drupal.org/project/media

Comment: you can still use mediafront. disable the display of the field on the node display settings, then use views to load the videos in a player with playlist using mediafront.

Comment: i cant seem to ue views to load the embedded video links, what media type should i use? regardless of what i check I cant seem to viw third party content in the osm player

Comment: to clarify, a playlist content type is created, in it is a field to input youtube urls. i want the display to be a mediafront player of those youtube url's. playlist is created internally but video is hosted externally